# Laravel redirect to root on request validation error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a required field in a Laravel Request Class and when that field is not present in the request,
the request is redirected to root '/'.

I am sending the request via Postman.

Comment: Also, I'm using basic.auth.

Comment: Are you building an API? Please add the code for controller in your question

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: The question is, why is it not generating the appropriate response e.g 'error: missing required field'. It's currently returning status code 200 and the html response of the welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

If laravel validator finds errors in the request it will redirect you back to the previous page with errors. If the request is AJAX however, it will return you a simple JSON response with a 422 status code.